# Simpson's Rule returning an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, scipy

Ok, so my Simpson's Rule is defined as:

```
def simpsonsRule(func, a, b, n, p0, r0):
    if n%2 == 1:
        return "Not applicable"
    else:
        h = (b - a) / float(n)
        s = func(a, p0, r0) + sum((4 if i%2 == 1 else 2) * func(a+i*h, p0, r0) for i in range(1,n)) + func(b, p0, r0)
        return s*h/3.0
```

Yet, when I do something like:

```
def integrate_NFW(rx,ps,rs):
    rho = ps/((r/rs)*((1+(r/rs))**2))
    function_result = rho * 4.0 * np.pi * rx**2
    return function_result
def chisqfuncNFW(iter_vars):
    global v_model
    #Normalizes p0 (p0 is too large relative to rc)
    ps = iter_vars[0] * 3.85e+09
    rs = iter_vars[1]
    for index in range(0, am):
        integral_result = simpsonsRule(integrate_NFW, 0.0, r[index], 200, ps, rs)
        print(integral_result)
```

When you print out integral_result it returns an array of numbers:

```
[  1.58771810e+13   3.68633515e+12   1.60346051e+12   8.81279407e+11
   5.37962555e+11   3.54826396e+11   2.49107306e+11   1.80747811e+11
   1.36318422e+11   1.05440828e+11   8.32851651e+10   6.66410643e+10
   5.41730944e+10   4.48302130e+10]
```

So `integral_result = simpsonsRule(integrate_NFW, 0.0, r[index], 200, ps, rs)` returns an array instead of one number

I would like to add that it works fine (it returns one number instead of an array) for another model of mine:

```
def integrate_Burk(rx,p0,r0):
    rho = (p0 * r0**3) / ( (rx + r0) * (rx**2 + r0**2) )
    function_result = rho * 4.0 * np.pi * rx**2
    return function_result
def chisqfuncBurk(iter_vars):
    global v_model
    #Normalizes p0 (p0 is too large relative to rc)
    p0 = iter_vars[0] * 3.85e+09
    r0 = iter_vars[1]
    v_model = []
    for index in range(0, am):
        integral_result = simpsonsRule(integrate_Burk, 0.0, r[index], 200, p0, r0)
```

Also, `r` is an array of numbers:

```
0.22
0.66
1.11
1.55
2.00
2.45
2.89
3.34
3.78
4.22
4.66
5.11
5.56
6.00
```

and `am` is the amount of numbers in `r` (in this case, I believe it is 14)

Let me know if I left anything out or if you want additional code

**EDIT** Here is some code that replicates the error

```
from scipy.optimize import*
import numpy as np
am = 14
r = np.array([0.22,
0.66,
1.11,
1.55,
2.00,
2.45,
2.89,
3.34,
3.78,
4.22,
4.66,
5.11,
5.56,
6.00])
def simpsonsRule(func, a, b, n, p0, r0):
    if n%2 == 1:
        return "Not applicable"
    else:
        h = (b - a) / float(n)
        s = func(a, p0, r0) + sum((4 if i%2 == 1 else 2) * func(a+i*h, p0, r0) for i in range(1,n)) + func(b, p0, r0)
        return s*h/3.0

def integrate_NFW(rx,ps,rs):
    rho = ps/((r/rs)*((1+(r/rs))**2))
    function_result = rho * 4.0 * np.pi * rx**2
    return function_result
def chisqfuncNFW(iter_vars):
    global v_model
    #Normalizes p0 (p0 is too large relative to rc)
    ps = iter_vars[0] * 3.85e+09
    rs = iter_vars[1]
    for index in range(0, am):
        integral_result = simpsonsRule(integrate_NFW, 0.0, r[index], 200, ps, rs)
        print(integral_result)
initial_guess = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
resNFW = minimize(chisqfuncNFW, initial_guess,method = 'Nelder-Mead')
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what the problem is. It would help to provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Comment: when I used simpson's rule for the Burk profile it works perfectly fine and returns a number. Yet when I do it for NFW profile, it returns an array. All the code you need to replicate it should be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the global array `r` in your function:

```
def integrate_NFW(rx,ps,rs):
    rho = ps/((r/rs)*((1+(r/rs))**2))
```

This turns `rho` into an array.

Comment: Oh... Ya, I meant to put rx instead of r in the equation for rho... thank you!